# How to find the length of a dynamically allocated array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I need to read inputs from a csv and put it into a dynamically allocated array
`Ay`.

```
int* Ay = malloc(nz * sizeof(int));
```

The number of inputs from the csv will vary in each case. Later I pass `Ay` to another function where I need to calculate its length. I have used the following methods but it doesn't give me the right result.

```
int Aylen = sizeof(Ay) / sizeof(Ay[0]);
```

or

```
int Aylen= 1[&Ay] - Ay;
```

or

```
int Aylen=*(&Ay+1)-Ay;
```

Please suggest a way to find the length. Thank you.

Comment: Keep track of the length in a variable.

Comment: `nz` already has the length. Just pass it as an extra argument to the functions.

Comment: You allocated it, so you already know the size.  A pointer is just a pointer, you need to pass the size as well as the pointer.

Comment: There's a list of frequently asked questions in the [tag info for C](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). You should take the time to read all of them, but at least the six that apply to arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no portable way to determine the size of a dynamically allocated buffer.  You need to keep track of that yourself.

This means you have to pass both `Ay` and `nz` to any function that accesses `Ay`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in C language.

You need to keep trach of the size.

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t length;
    int data[];
}data_t;


data_t *add_element(data_t *arr, int element)
{
    size_t newsize = arr ? arr -> length + 1 : 0;
    arr = realloc(arrr, newsize * sizeof(arr -> data[0]) + sizeof(*arr));
    
    if(arr)
    {
        arr -> length = newsize;
        arr -> data[newsize - 1] = element;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I'd do: `int *data` and add `size_t capacity`

Comment: @CraigEstey why double reference?

Comment: What you did _is_ valid [and may be the best solution for a memory constrained MCU]. But, with `int *data` the struct mimics a C++ `vector` impl. After doing (e.g.): `data_t *arr = calloc(1,sizeof(*arr));` to create it, all functions [that resize or _don't_ resize] can be: `void func(data_t *arr,...)` Otherwise, we'd need: `data_t *arrgrow(data_t *arr,...)` or `void arrgrow(data_t **arr,...)` and `void arrnogrow(data_t *arr,...)`. The caller needs to keep track of more things.

Comment: @CraigEstey no we do not need any double pointers. Avoiding side effects is the best way.